# android - download the image from url not displaying correctly

Tags: android, image

In my app, when you click on the button then I am downloading the images from the url's. It displaying the images some time correctly but some time it display empty. ***problem is some times bitmap object(i.e, "result" in code ) return null.***please can anybody help me.

Following is my code

```
try
            {

          String ImageUrl = ((eachReview)RB_Constant.revht.get(title_value)).UserImageUrl;  
          System.out.println("Image Url:"+ImageUrl);
          if(ImageUrl != null)
          {
              DownLoadImageInAThreadHandler(ImageUrl,holder);                                                                       
          }
          else
          {
              System.out.println("Image url is null then display the default image");
              holder.userImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.defaultuserimage);
          }
       }
       catch(Exception e){
           System.out.println("Error from Userimage fetching.."+e.toString());
       }



private void DownLoadImageInAThreadHandler(final String imgurl,final ViewHolder holder)
 { 



    //Thread for getting the attributes values
     Thread t = new Thread() 
     {
         public void run()
         {                      
             try
             {

                 Bitmap drawable = getDrawableFromUrl(imgurl);                      
                 System.out.println("Drawable(after downloading):"+drawable);                        
                 if(drawable != null)
                 {                                              
                    holder.userImage.setImageBitmap(drawable);                      
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     System.out.println("after downloading drawable is null then set the default image");
                     holder.userImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.defaultuserimage);
                 }                                               
             }
             catch(Exception exp)
             {
                 System.out.println("Exception in DownLoadImageInAThread : " + exp.getMessage());
             }
         }

         private Bitmap getDrawableFromUrl(String imageUrl)
         {                               
                 try 
                 {
                     URL myFileUrl = new URL(imageUrl);
                     HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myFileUrl.openConnection();                       
                     conn.setDoInput(true);
                     conn.connect();
                     InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                     final Bitmap result = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                     is.close();
                     new Thread() {
                         public void run() {
                             ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                             if(result != null)
                             {
                                 result.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);
                             }                                                                                                  
                         }
                     }.start();                         
                     return result;
                 } 
                 catch (FileNotFoundException e)
                 {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
                 catch (MalformedURLException e)
                 {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 } 
                 catch (IOException e) 
                 {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
                 return null;                               
         }                                                  
     };
     t.start();                             
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the image Url in browser? Is image available there? It may be possible that image you are trying to download is not available on the URL provided.

Comment: yes,the image is available. plz check my thread calling is correct?

Comment: Have you considered switching to picasso ? [here] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22330772/why-to-use-android-picasso-library-to-download-the-images

Answer (score 0):

Try making you getDrawableFromUrl as:

```
public static Drawable getDrawableFromUrl(String url) {

    Drawable image = null;

    try {
        InputStream in = (java.io.InputStream) new java.net.URL(url).getContent();
        if (in != null) {
            image = Drawable.createFromStream(in, "image");
            in.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();

    }
    return image;
}
```

Also do not compress image within same function. Try Doing it after you successfully receive an image. One thing more that write getDrawableFromUrl function out of the thread but in same class. Hope this works for you.

Comment: Still some time it returns null

Comment: This is strange. The reason seems that image isn't available at the url that i told you earlier. but according to you image is available. Ok tell me randomly images become null or same images are null every time?

Comment: One thing...are your images .gif ? because sometimes .gif images create problem. Images are not null but still the do not show up.

Comment: .jpg, .png or .gif  ??? because all are types of bitmap. See documentation.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

Comment: url is like this http://www.roadbrake.com/ImageServer/ThumbImage/00e46e81-7587-4ee3-a0b3-513a71fb2bfc