# Doesn't Picasso support to download images which uses https protocol

Tags: android, picasso

Hello I am using the `Picasso` library to download the images from URL.

URL : https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-prn2/t1.0-1/s200x200/1472865_191408954385576_14109897_n.jpg

URL is using https protocol, here it is not working for me to download the images of https protocol using `Picasso`.

Doesn't it support to download the images which uses https protocol, it worked for me only if I use http proctocol ?

Here I am trying to get bitmap which is using https protocol

```
com.squareup.picasso.Target target = new com.squareup.picasso.Target() {

@Override
public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, LoadedFrom loadedFrom) {
    userProfile.setBitmap(bitmap);
    // call the Web API to register the walker here
    new AudioStreetAsyncTask(getActivity(), userProfile, getString(R.string.registration_processing_message), new TaskCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTaskCompleted(String jsonResponse) {
           Log.d(TAG, jsonResponse);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable drawable) {
    userProfile.setBitmap(null);
    // call the Web API to register the walker here
    new AudioStreetAsyncTask(getActivity(), userProfile, getString(R.string.registration_processing_message), new TaskCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTaskCompleted(String jsonResponse) {
           Log.d(TAG, jsonResponse);
        }
    }).execute();
}

@Override
public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable drawable) {}
};

Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(imgUrl.toString()).into(target);
```

Any idea ?

Comment: can you please up vote and accept my solution as correct as it is up to date and the solution given by nexus700120 is outdated.

Answer (score 36):

Use those dependencies in your `Gradle`:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
```

And this class instead of the original `Picasso` class

Picasso class:

```
 public class PicassoTrustAll {

    private static Picasso mInstance = null;

    private PicassoTrustAll(Context context) {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        client.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String s, SSLSession sslSession) {
                return true;
            }
        });
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(
                    java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] x509Certificates,
                    String s) throws java.security.cert.CertificateException {
            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(
                    java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] x509Certificates,
                    String s) throws java.security.cert.CertificateException {
            }

            @Override
            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] {};
            }
        } };
        try {
            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
            client.setSslSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mInstance = new Picasso.Builder(context)
                .downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(client))
                .listener(new Picasso.Listener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception) {
                        Log.e("PICASSO", exception);
                    }
                }).build();

    }

    public static Picasso getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
             new PicassoTrustAll(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
PicassoTrustAll.getInstance(context)
                .load(url)
                .into(imageView);
```

Comment: It works fine only with those dependencies http://stackoverflow.com/a/28251889/1364896

Comment: it's working fine but not for all the devices. example nexus4

Comment: It's work like champ.. Thank you so much for this solution.

Comment: Could you update the code using okhttp3? You should not use these dependencies anymore since your app will start to crash (java.util.NoSuchElementException). Retrofit 2 does not need okhttp dependency. If you have it you are mixing dependencies and it's not good. Thanks

Comment: Perfect solution!

Comment: Thanks, your solution saved me. But Since I had used Retrofit2 in my project, I had to use okhttp3 and updated the above solution accordingly. But this method didn't work on the latest Picasso version (2.71828) that I use, and I had to downgrade Picasso version to 2.4 as your solution! How we can apply this solution for Picasso 2.71828 with okhttp3? @crubio also mentioned this point, I don't know if he could find compatible dependency.

Answer (score 3):

@nexus700120 solution is not up to date

@Neha Tyagi solution works but creates multiple instances of `Picasso` in each instance of activity which leaks memory

So I crafted a up to date and singleton solution for redirecting image URLs -

CustomPicasso.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import com.jakewharton.picasso.OkHttp3Downloader;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

/**
 * Created by Hrishikesh Kadam on 19/12/2017
 */

public class CustomPicasso {

    private static String LOG_TAG = CustomPicasso.class.getSimpleName();
    private static boolean hasCustomPicassoSingletonInstanceSet;

    public static Picasso with(Context context) {

        if (hasCustomPicassoSingletonInstanceSet)
            return Picasso.with(context);

        try {
            Picasso.setSingletonInstance(null);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.w(LOG_TAG, "-> Default singleton instance already present" +
                    " so CustomPicasso singleton cannot be set. Use CustomPicasso.getNewInstance() now.");
            return Picasso.with(context);
        }

        Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(context).
                downloader(new OkHttp3Downloader(context))
                .build();

        Picasso.setSingletonInstance(picasso);
        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "-> CustomPicasso singleton set to Picasso singleton." +
                " In case if you need Picasso singleton in future then use Picasso.Builder()");
        hasCustomPicassoSingletonInstanceSet = true;

        return picasso;
    }

    public static Picasso getNewInstance(Context context) {

        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "-> Do not forget to call customPicasso.shutdown()" +
                " to avoid memory leak");

        return new Picasso.Builder(context).
                downloader(new OkHttp3Downloader(context))
                .build();
    }
}
```

build.gradle (Module:app)

```
android {

    ...

}

dependencies {

    ...

    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.1.0'
}
```

Usage -

```
CustomPicasso.with(context)
    .load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png")
    .into(imageView);
```

For latest revisions check CustomPicasso gist - https://gist.github.com/hrishikesh-kadam/09cef31c736de088313f1a102f5ed3a3

Comment: I have tried this solution in my app and it does not work with https protocol. Keep in mind that this is what the question is about

Comment: @crubio Can you please give me which URL are you hitting?

Comment: You can try this one for example: https://www.multiestetica.com/img/img_et/avatar/i-avatar-15.jpg

Comment: @crubio It is working my friend. Created play app, take pull and let me know again if it doesn't work - https://github.com/hrishikesh-kadam/custom-picasso-play

Comment: @crubio Just make sure that you don't make a call to Picasso.with(context) before CustomPicasso.with(context). As this would fall back to original Picasso working. You can verify by checking log as I have logged warning.

Comment: Your play app works. You should put last version of retrofit as dependency though. Anyway, I still don't know why in my project it does not work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161814/discussion-between-hrishikesh-kadam-and-crubio).

Comment: Finally it worked, I think I was experiencing issues with the server cache. Anyway I detected an issue with hasCustomPicassoSingletonInstanceSet. It seems to use original Picasso and I don't want this to happen ever.

Comment: @crubio still getting ssl handshake error but : multiestetica.com/img/img_et/avatar/i-avatar-15.jpg  image is working fine please suggest on this.

Answer (score 2):

```
 final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .protocols(Collections.singletonList(Protocol.HTTP_1_1))
                    .build();

            Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(mContext)
                    .downloader(new OkHttp3Downloader(client))
                    .build();
picasso .with(mContext).load(YOUR_URL).into(YOUR_IMAGEVIEW);
```

Add

```
compile 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.1.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put this this code in your Application class:

```
final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .protocols(Collections.singletonList(Protocol.HTTP_1_1))
        .build();

final Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(this)
        .downloader(new OkHttp3Downloader(client))
        .build();

Picasso.setSingletonInstance(picasso);
```

from this [link](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/500#issuecomment-210645018) check it.

Answer (score 1):

The following works fine for these dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

First  define a client to accept certificates:

```
public class SelfSignCertHttpClient {
    public static OkHttpClient getSelfSignOkHttpClient(List<Interceptor> interceptors) {
        try {
            final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
                    new X509TrustManager() {
                        @Override
                        public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                            return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[]{};
                        }
                    }
            };

            final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());

            final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

            OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
            builder.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, (X509TrustManager)trustAllCerts[0]);
            builder.hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                    return true;
                }
            });

            for (Interceptor interceptor : interceptors) {
                builder.addInterceptor(interceptor);
            }

            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = builder.build();
            return okHttpClient;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Source: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-trust-unsafe-ssl-certificates-self-signed-expired

I have also added the option to pass a list of interceptors when creating the client.

You can than define a PicasoTrustAll class:

```
public class PicassoTrustAll {

    private static Picasso mInstance = null;

    private PicassoTrustAll(Context context) {
        List<Interceptor> interceptors = new ArrayList<>();
        // Add any interceptors you wish (e.g Authorization Header interceptor)

        mInstance = new Picasso.Builder(context)
                .downloader(new OkHttp3Downloader(SelfSignCertHttpClient.getSelfSignOkHttpClient(interceptors)))
                .listener((picasso, uri, exception) -> Log.e("PICASSO", exception.getMessage())).build();

    }

    public static Picasso getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            new PicassoTrustAll(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
PicassoTrustAll.getInstance(this).load("https://10.0.2.2/path/to/picture").into(mainPictureView);
```