# Image from certain Url is not load in picasso

Tags: android, caching, picasso

I load image from URL using `picasso` first time on line, After then use from cache. Any URL from web is load in `imageview` on line or off line. But my server image URL is load image in on line not in off line. I use below code from image load.

```
 Picasso.with(mContext)
            .load(urlProfile)
            .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_place_holder)
            .into(imageView, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError() {
                    Picasso.with(mContext)
                            .load(urlProfile)
                            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_place_holder)
                            .into(imageView);
                }
            });
```

Web url load in online or offline both : **[URL](https://beebom-redkapmedia.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Reverse-Image-Search-Engines-Apps-And-Its-Uses-2016.jpg)**

My server url load image only in online: **[URL](http://eatit-nodejs.vm52.sa92.sa-labs.info/uploads/5a2e280840a5d1a53ac89492.jpg)**

I show in cache directory and found that image of my server URL is not cached. Any have idea about that.

Comment: Try Glide instead of Piccaso for better result

Comment: or refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/35236517/8416317

Comment: My suggestion to use Glide/Fresco for Loading images

Answer (score 3):

Hi below is my solutions and it's working perfectlly.

```
Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(Uri.parse(urlProfile))
                .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
                .into(iv_view, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        // if you are showing progress then handle it on here
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                        // Try again online if cache failed and download using internet                          
                        new Picasso.Builder(mContext)
                                .downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(mContext, Integer.MAX_VALUE))
                                .build()
                                .load(Uri.parse(urlProfile))
                                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                                .into(iv_view);
                    }
                });
```

Hope this helps you..

By the way this is very old but you can use Glide for better performance.

Comment: Consider commenting what you have changed

Comment: I have changes like :  
`new Picasso.Builder(mContext)
                                .downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(mContext, Integer.MAX_VALUE))
                                .build()`

Comment: i think it's helped you