# I do not see the photos that I use with Picasso in the okhttp library?

Tags: java, android, picasso, android-studio-3.0

**I use the OKHTTP library to have Picasso auto-cache photos. I run this with a class. But I do not see the photos with Picasso when I'm working like this. I ran it by adding Android Manifest. "android: name.Global" I have removed the photo from it. What is the problem ? I'm sorry for my terrible english. Thanks in advance.**

My build.gradle;

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

**My Global.java**

```
import android.app.Application;
import com.jakewharton.picasso.OkHttp3Downloader;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
public class Global extends Application {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(this)
            .downloader(new OkHttp3Downloader(this,Integer.MAX_VALUE))
            .build();
    picasso.setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
    picasso.setLoggingEnabled(true);
    Picasso.setSingletonInstance(picasso);

}
}
```

**My Android MAnifest.xml;**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:name=".Global"
```

**My java for Picasso;**

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_promotion, container, 
    false);

    IntroImage01 = (KenBurnsView)view.findViewById(R.id.IntroImage01);

    mDatabase.child("IntroImage01").addValueEventListener(new 
    ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String url = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

            Picasso.get()
                    .load(url)
                    .into(IntroImage01);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

My codes work, but as I said, I do not see pictures when I add global.

Comment: where is your url?

Comment: I have a url. I get Url from the database.

Comment: That url loading in browser usually?

Comment: I think you should load into an `ImageView`. Could you show detail your `IntroImage01` on `Picasso.get()` please?

Comment: try this :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/47769340/3974530

Comment: I updated. I'm sorry I left out.

Comment: Have you ever tried to load the image by using `Picasso` with `ImageView` instead of `KenBurnsView` before?

Comment: Yes, I tried. My application also has KenBurn and ImageView in different activities. When global is deactivated, they all work fine. But when I add Android Manifest, I can not get images in ImageView or KenBurn.