# android image not display with https protocol

Tags: android, picasso

Hi Friends I want your help to solve my issue if you have any idea please tell.

I want to show image on list view.When I use http protocol image display fine but when i use HTTPS image not display.

I used Picasso to display image on image view

Hear is my code what i used

```
Picasso.with(mContext).load("https://velocityagency.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/go.jpg").into(imgProduct);
```

thanks in advance

Comment: @user3289108 did you even read the question?

Comment: Now I got my solution from hear http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23562794/doesnt-picasso-support-to-download-images-which-uses-https-protocol

Answer (score 1):

> https://velocityagency.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/go.jpg

This is happening because the image URL is having a problem. Try to fix this issue first, then your image will load properly in android app

[image]