# Picasso won't load Instagram image in android

Tags: android, instagram, picasso

Using Picasso I want to load images from Instagram media url like :

```
https://instagram.com/p/7-6FIJjMym/media/
```

The url returns a `HTTP/1.1 302 FOUND` and a location header for redirection like:

```
https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xpt1/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/1530612_903806373047604_222778181_n.jpg
```

Here is my code:

```
String url="https://instagram.com/p/7-6FIJjMym/media/"
Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(url).into((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView));
```

Here is my log:

```
12-01 10:40:33.134 18439-18439/ D/Picasso: Main        created      [R0] Request{https://instagram.com/p/7-6FIJjMym/media/}
12-01 10:40:33.139 18439-18542/ D/Picasso: Dispatcher  enqueued     [R0]+5ms 
12-01 10:40:33.142 18439-18544/ D/Picasso: Hunter      executing    [R0]+8ms
```

It won't load the image.

Comment: @AntonShkurenko Updated. url is set to `https://instagram.com/p/7-6FIJjMym/media/`

Comment: Seems like this is wrong url, Picasso can't load an image from redirect. Pass to it good url.

Comment: maybe it cant get images from https  -- https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/500  -- if thats the case someone says in there that universal image loader can do https by default

Comment: also have alook here for a possible solution --- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23562794/doesnt-picasso-support-to-download-images-which-uses-https-protocol/26398617#26398617

Comment: @Tasos Thanks, I will take a look.