# Android Image fetching library

Tags: android, imageview

Hi  i wanted to know is their any library in which we pass the URL and the image-view and it checks whether the images is present  on device if not, then fetch image from URL and store to device and bind with the view passed. I tried writing the code but once the view is loaded and image is not fetched the images is never fetched in future unless i uninstall the app , i also tried universal image loader library and asynchronous image loader

Answer (score 1):

**[Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso)** is doing all things what you want.

1. It loads from internet and cache
2. It loads from cache
3. It loads from Local File

**[Read More Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24076798/3884250)** And **[Here](http://square.github.io/picasso/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try volley library. you have a NetworkImageView I guess. Which fits your need.