# Image are not displaying from Cache memory using Picasso Library

Tags: android, picasso

I am using **Picasso** library for image download and displaying it in imageView. This library also store images in cache and memory. When my internet is turn on, i am able to view images on imageView. So i think, it should also be store in cache or file memory. Now my internet is turnOFF, but it doest not display to images. kindly have a look.

```java
Picasso.with(context)
  .load(url) .placeholder(R.drawable.defaultimg)
  .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
  .into(holder.imageview2,  new ImageLoadedCallback(holder.loadingBar) {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
        if (holder.loadingBar != null) {
            holder.loadingBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onError(){
        holder.loadingBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Picasso.with(context)
          .load(url) .placeholder(R.drawable.defaultimg)
          .into(holder.imageview2,  new ImageLoadedCallback(holder.loadingBar) {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                if (holder.loadingBar != null) {
                    holder.loadingBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {
                if (holder.loadingBar != null) {
                    holder.loadingBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: When your internet is **OFF**, no matter images are cached or not, the source tends to be corrected for the library, so it throws exception and do not display the cached Image. Either download the image and provide the local path when internet is off, or provide a proper placeholder image in case of no internet.

Comment: @MohammedAtif I don't believe that's the case. [Jake addressed this issue in the Picasso issue tracker here.](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/698#issuecomment-58745858)

Comment: @Mohammed Atif my app that use picasso cache images, and display them even when internet is off.

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22330772/why-use-android-picasso-library-to-download-images

Comment: In that case, did you try removing the NetworkPolicy builder?

Comment: @MohammedAtif yes i added **     .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)** so it will load from cache not internet but doest not work.

Comment: Remove that and try. **Forces the request through the disk cache only, skipping network** Let it handle automatically. And on second note, I personally use Glide because of its efficiency and it handles the caching internally.

Comment: @MohammedAtif Just removed. First all images are displaying. I closed to app , turnOFF internet, Open app Now no one images are displaying.

Comment: Why don't you use `.error(R.drawable.defaultimg)` instead of calling `Picasso.with` for the second time?

Comment: Check that the `url` is not empty / null when you're offline

Comment: @dev.bmax Fantastic! Url was not correct. I was using ** http://xxxxx.com/fe9d6.jpg?960|720** this url but picasso autometically handle and rendering that url when internet ON. I just removed **960|720** and works

Answer (score 0):

Finally I resolved that issue. Thanks @dev.bmax

image url was not correct. There is **bug in Picasso**. If we have url like as

https://i.ytimg.com/vi/DMVEcfQmPOs/maxresdefault.jpg?500|700

Picasso is able to displaying image when internet **TURN ON** 
but if we **TURN OFF** to internet, it does not decode the url. and not display the image also.

We have to remove **?500|700** then i was able to view image in OFFLine mode also. 
  //url.substring(0,url.indexOf("?"))

https://i.ytimg.com/vi/DMVEcfQmPOs/maxresdefault.jpg

Thanks!